# Saint/St./St/ST in institution names in capital letters

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations

When writing the name of an institution which is named after a saint (e.g. Univetsity of Mining and Geology St Ivan Rilski) in capital letters in an official document, should one use

UNIVERSITY OF MINING AND GEOLOGY ST IVAN RILSKI

UNIVERSITY OF MINING AND GEOLOGY St IVAN RILSKI

UNIVERSITY OF MINING AND GEOLOGY SAINT IVAN RILSKI

or something else?

Is the usage of the full "saint" totally incorrect?

(The Cambridge guide to English usage distinguishes usage of St(.) in names of institutions and in names of geographical places, like cities, which makes this question, I think, not a duplicate.)

Comment: The answer is always the same. If you have an authority (the institution itself, the town council, the board of the company ... copy their practice if you can find an example. [As here](http://bg.total.com/en/university-mining-and-geology-st-ivan-rilski). These authorities trump general style guides.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Reasonable research should be provided even where this does not give a complete (or even any) answer.

Answer (score -1):

"… ST IVAN RILSKI" -- in line with AllCaps. "St." as in this context is never written in full form.

See also:
[UNIVERSITY OF MINING AND GEOLOGY, "ST. IVAN RILSKI"](http://www.mgu.bg/index_en.html) (Univ. website)
[St. Ivan Rilski – the patron saint of Bulgarian people](http://bnr.bg/en/post/100172932/st-ivan-rilski-the-patron-saint-of-bulgarian-people) Radio Bulgaria